# python fnmatch unable to find the file

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a directory that has bunch of sub directories, each subdir has many csv files, but I am only interest in certain csv file. So I wrote following python method, but I am unable to capture the file name, if I do *.csv it will find all the file but I don't want to all the files to be read in:

```
def gatherStats(template_file, csv_file):
    for lang in getLanguageCodes(csv_file):
        lang_dir = os.path.join(template_file, lang)
        try:
            for file in os.listdir(lang_dir):
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*-*-template-users-data.csv'):
                    t_file = open(file, 'rb').read()
                    reader = csv.reader()
                    for row in reader:
                        print row
                else:
                    print "didn't find the file"
        except Exception, e:
            logging.exception(e)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is it a regular expression issue? Can we use regular expression with fnmath?

Comment: Can you share some examples of filenames that should match? I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: A change I would suggest is changing your `else:` statement to something like: `print "file %s didn't match" % file`, if your print statment never prints, then you're probably trying to list the contents of the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help provided by another user, I manage to fix the problem. I am putting this answer here for future reference for community.

```
def gatherStats(template_file, csv_file):
    for lang in getLanguageCodes(csv_file):
        lang_dir = os.path.join(template_file, lang)
        try:
            for filename in os.listdir(lang_dir):
                path = os.path.join(lang_dir, filename)
                if re.search(r'-.+-template-users-data.csv$',filename):
                    with open(path, 'rb') as template_user_data_file:
                        reader = csv.reader(template_user_data_file)
                        try:
                            for row in reader:
                                print row
                        except csv.ERROR as e:
                            logging.error(e)
                else:
                    print "didn't find the file"
        except Exception, e:
            logging.exception(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code. Fix them first, then we might get to the bottom of what your issue really is.

- First of all, don't use built-in names as variables, such as `file`. Rather replace it with `filename`.
- Then `os.path.join(lang_dir, filename)` before opening the file. Meaning:

  ```
  t_file = open(os.path.join(lang_dir, filename), 'rb').read()
  ```
- How do you expect `reader = csv.reader()` to read your file if you don't reference your open file object in this line?
- Your `try`/`except` block is a bit too wide for my taste. Take your time and narrow down the errors that actually can happen. Then decide which of them you want to ignore and which should crash your program. Take a close look at the exceptions actually thrown in this block. You'll probably find your issue there.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts but this actually didn't provide an answer, so I had to down vote. I manage to fix the issue and cleanup the code that I had with the help of the answer provided by a different user. But some how i Don't see that answer anymore.

Comment: Glad I could help (you have followed three of my pointers). The `fnmatch` was not your issue: `from fnmatch import fnmatch`, `test = "AAA-BBB-template.csv"`, `fnmatch(test, '*-*-template.csv')` -> `True`. This was already pointed out by Martijn Pieters.